# What is the difference between context_dict and context in django, python?

Tags: python, django

I was always using context in my methods until I came across on this view:

```
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    top_category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]

    for category in top_category_list:
        category.url = encode_url(category.name)

    context_dict = {'categories': top_category_list}

    cat_list = get_category_list()
    context_dict['cat_list'] = cat_list

    page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
    context_dict['pages'] = page_list

    if request.session.get('last_visit'):
    # The session has a value for the last visit
        last_visit_time = request.session.get('last_visit')

        visits = request.session.get('visits', 0)

        if (datetime.now() - datetime.strptime(last_visit_time[:-7], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")).days > 0:
            request.session['visits'] = visits + 1
    else:
        # The get returns None, and the session does not have a value for the last visit.
        request.session['last_visit'] = str(datetime.now())
        request.session['visits'] = 1

    # Render and return the rendered response back to the user.
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context_dict, context)
```

In above function there are context_dict and context? Why is that?

Also is there a difference between: 
    context_dict = {'categories': top_category_list}
and
    context_dict['categories'] = top_category_list

or this is exactly the same ?

Thank you guys!

Comment: is this code working properly ?

Comment: This code is from tutorial that was following although my index view is slightly different than that one because this one confused me completely with these context_dict and context, so not sure if this code exactly works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `context_dict` is a simple dictionary
- `context` is an instance or RequestContext

inside `render_to_response()` `context_dict` is (temporary) added to the `context` instance

the code (in this case)  can be written more clearly (IMHO) as:

```
def index(request):
    top_category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    for category in top_category_list:
        category.url = encode_url(category.name)

    page_list = Page.objects.order_by('-views')[:5]
    cat_list = get_category_list()

    context_dict = {'categories': top_category_list, 
                    'pages': page_list, 
                    'cat_list': cat_list}

    context = RequestContext(request, context_dict)
    return render_to_response('rango/index.html', context=context)
```

if django >= 1.3 you can change last two lines with

```
    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context_dict)
```

about your other question

`context_dict = {'categories': top_category_list}`  create e new dict

`context_dict['categories'] = top_category_list` assign (or add) a new entry into an **existing** dictionary

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Although I am still confused.. why can not we use just one context?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost exactly the same, the first one is defining new dictionary and putting new key/values in it, whereas the second one is just putting new key:value in it because the dic has been already defined.

In modern django, you do

```
return render(request, 'index.html', context_dic)
```

Where render already handles RequestContext for you. This way may save some confuses

Comment: in render_to_response we use context_dict and context and in render only one context? is this correct?

Comment: @Anita no, in ``render`` you dont need to use ``context``, you just need template context which is ``context_dict`` in this example

Answer (score 0):

Actually in Django 1.11 this small change seems to work.

Define the dict: (context not needed, only the dict)
Then change the line to take the dict:

return render_to_response('rango/index.html',  context_dict)

Which makes more sense for a template view, you read from the request and return the response with the (result) context.

Note: This may not work in cases when additional information is needed from header (request)